# Tenant has many domains

Tags: multi-tenant

In, Ruby on Rails ,I want to create multiple domains from admin .Here the domains are tied to a single tenant.Tenant has many domains.

How to accomplish this.Is there any way to create domain from admin UI? But the domain should be tied to a single tenant.

Also I want to test the tenant is working or not? Please give some suggestions along with links if any?

Comment: What language and framework are you working with?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you do a simple wild card mapping in your cpanel domain mapping and then create the the tenants with the sub domain name as tenant like Google.yourapp.com. when the tenant user hits the URL the sub domain mapping will point to your code base and the task is simple. Let me know if this woks fine for your case.